# Blacklist the ubuntu-desktop tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-block-request

Is it possible to blacklist that tag? I don't see it go away without a little extra help.

Comment: ignore the bump, just trying to remove cruft from this list

Answer (score 6):

The [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) tag would also need to be blacklisted, because it redirects to [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: why does the [ubuntu] tag even exist? These both need to be removed -- and I have done so.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - migrations from the trilogy and people with a poor understanding of the scope of this site :)

Comment: @marco ah yes, we are improving migrations to deal with better tag handling including stuff like "don't add a blacklisted tag to a site" .. I have added `^ubuntu(-desktop)?$` to the regex tag blacklist here to assist.

Answer (score 3):

Does it really need to be *blacklisted*?

I have deleted [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) and [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) for now.

edit: this was also blacklisted as `^ubuntu(-desktop)?$`

Comment: No, probably not. It's not all that helpful though as far as I can determine.