# Found An Orphaned Synonym Tag

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Tag [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) is a synonym of tag [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) which I think has been deleted???
My understanding is that since it's a synonym tag the system won't automatically remove it 
like it does with normal tags that see no use, and so I just thought I'd mention it on here.
Out of curiosity why doesn't the system automatically delete synonyms when the master is killed, or is this a fluke find?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of ubuntu tag search results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The historical order of events:

1. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/34/discouraging-ubuntu-tags
2. [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) was merge-synonymised into [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) because it was implied.
3. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/789/deprecate-the-ubuntu-desktop-tag

   Notably the [comment from Jeff](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/789/deprecate-the-ubuntu-desktop-tag#comment1055_790) on the first answer:

   > if anything you should tag server questions [server] to differentiate them and assume most questions are about desktop.
4. [Then both  were both blacklisted by Jeff](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/973/blacklist-the-ubuntu-desktop-tag). It's still impossible to use either tag.

---

The synonym is a redundancy, you're right. But it also doesn't hurt, it being there. If one day the blacklist does get altered or lost, at least we'll only have one place to hunt.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it's not magically deleted so that the things that were tagged that way could be indexed in order to put them under new tags if required.

Clarity: I'm guessing, but it would make sense.